# Sharepoint 2010 : XSS attacks

Tags: 2010, 2013, security

Recently i found out that application in sharepoint 2010 vulnerable to XSS attacks .
http://tools.cisco.com/security/center/viewAlert.x?alertId=34048

The XSS attack is something like :  an attacker can upload a javascript file in doc library and can perform some kind invalid actions , operations etc . But how do i prevent it from happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you visit [CVE](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-26/product_id-11116/Microsoft-Sharepoint-Server.html) and their are tons of XSS Vulnerabilities related to SharePoint versions. I check from all, only 1 have workaround.

- **Disable or rename user accounts with suspicious usernames**
  Disable or rename all user accounts with usernames containing double quotes, angle brackets, HTML markup, or JavaScript code, such as the following:

  `>< img src=x onerror=prompt(1)>`

[Vulnerabilities in Microsoft Office Could Allow Remote Code Execution (3038999)](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms15-022?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

But I would recommend, update your farm to latest CU, may help in these issue.